# Why function declaration doesn't work in app.use?

Tags: node.js, express

When I use `foo` function declaration in `app.use` as a middleware the compiler doesn't seem to recognize the `req, res, next` variables:

```
var express = require('express');
var path  = require('path');
var app = express();

function foo (req, res, next){ // the middleware
    console.log(req.path);
}

app.use('/', foo(req, res, next)); //ReferenceError: req is not defined

app.use('/', express.static("./public"));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

By comparison if I use function declaration inside `app.use` the code works as intended:

```
var express = require('express');
var path  = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.path);
}); //ReferenceError: req is not defined

app.use('/', express.static("./public"));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

My understanding is not enough to see why this is an error

Comment: app.use('/', foo); would work. The previous version you are calling the function

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `app.use('/', foo(req, res, next));` is calling the function and executing it as it parses through the JS file.

The other 'comparison', is a function declaration which isn't called while parsing through the file.

You can change the code to: `app.use('/', foo);` and it'll work properly.